# Selenium ng-click

Tags: .net, angularjs, selenium

I have a list of items in an ng-repeat. I need to click a given item in the list using Selenium.

```
        var items = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@ng-repeat='filter in date_filters']"));
        items[1].Click();
```

items comes back with a list of all items, but items[1].click throws an error.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work would be appreciated.

Thanks,
George

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually .click operation on a webelement  works .If not use the java script executor.

Option 1:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='filter in date_filters']"));
elements.get(1).click();
```

Option 2:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='filter in date_filters']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elements.get(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks prithvi394,

You put me on to the right track;

My solution was;

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");

        var action = new Actions(driver);
        var mySlot = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@ng-repeat='filter in date_filters' and contains(., '29 Dec')]"));
        action.MoveToElement(mySlot).Click().Perform();
```

Oddly, I had to scroll the web browser in to a position where the button I wanted to click was visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to use array to collect list of items

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//*[@ng-repeat='filter in date_filters']"))

li.get(1).click();

//If you want to click the second element then get(1)
```